# Mongodb select distinct object with criteria

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection in mongodb use to save user's location sent by their phone every 60 seconds.

The fields in the collection: `uuid`(string), `x`(number),`y`(number),`updated`(date)

Data may looks like this:

```
uuid    x               y               updated
14      14.2038615      32.6570774      12:30:20
13      13.8059234      32.5008671      12:31:10
13      13.8061132      32.5008891      12:32:10
13      13.8061434      32.5008511      12:33:10
14      14.2039196      32.6570243      12:31:20
```

Now I want to get the distinct devices (by uuid) and there latest location, like this:

```
uuid    x               y               updated
14      14.2039196      32.6570243      12:31:20
13      13.8061434      32.5008511      12:33:10
```

And now I can get the distinct phone by:

```
db.location.distinct('uuid');
```

And I can get the latest location for a specified deivce:

```
db.location.find({uuid:12}).sort({updated:-1}).limit(1)
```

So I can select the distinct uuids, and then get the latest location for each, but I wonder if I can select them by one mongodb selection?

BTW, any suggestion for the index building in my case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) here as opposed to the other commands you are trying. This allows a "grouping bondary" to be set up, so you get the same results as "multiple" `.find()` queries:

```js
db.location.aggregate([
    { "$sort": { "uuid": 1, "updated": -1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$uuid",
        "x": { "$first": "$x" },
        "y": { "$first": "$y" }
    }}
])
```

Ideally you probably also want a [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage in there to do something like "filter the dates to a range" or essentially reduce the working data rather than go over the whole collection. It's good practice.

Basically you use [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) to order the results how you intend to "group" them, which is by "uuid" and in "updated" order. Then you [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) on "uuid" as the key, taking only the [**`$first`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) matched items after the sort has occurred by that "uuid" boundary.

That's how you do it with one query to the database rather than cycling all the possible "uuid" values in individual queries.

Look at the full range of [aggregation operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) for more usage examples as well as the [SQL to Aggregate Mapping Chart](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/) for some common examples of queries you might be used to and how they translate.

Comment: Thanks! I will go to the document.:)

Comment: And BTW, I do have to load over the whole collections when the application start. And since the insertion to the db will be triggered so frequently, the records will increase shaply, take 1000 devices for example, there will be 1000 * 24 * 60 = 1440000 records one day, any practice to optimize it?

Comment: @hguser Pre-aggregation would be the best optimization approach. In short, try to store your data only to the "frequency" that you actually use, or at least keep "pre-aggregated" copies. People always think "store everything", but that is often not practical. Really is another question in itself, and the usages are as broad as your own desired outcomes.